# How to make GraphicsGrids Legends at the end or below for all graphs

Tags: graphics

I combined 9 graphs using the `GraphicsGrid` command. Each graph has six curves.  Now I want to draw the legends after combining 9 graphs and showing legends below but not below of each graph.  How I do this?

Comment: Maybe put your GraphicsGrid inside a Column where the last element is a SwatchLegend. If you provide some code you will likely get  more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier for me just to build my own legend and insert it in. Something you can use is `GridBox` to insert your functions then apply a graphic in the last row. This isn't exactly what you described and its a bit messy, but I think you will get the point.

Lets assign the functions we are plotting to an array:

```
functions = {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6};
```

Now, just build your legend entries using whatever line type/shape your graphs have on them using `Graphics` and set the name of the function next to the entries (this is not completely perfect here, it takes some trial and error on the dimensions and placement)

```
lines = Flatten[
  Table[{Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{-.25, 0}, {-0, 0}}]}], 
     Scaled[{0.4, 0.89 - i/10}]], 
    Inset[Style[functions[[i]], 12, Italic], 
     Scaled[{0.53, 0.9 - i/10}]]}, {i, 1, 6}]]
```

Put these legend entries in a white box

```
legend = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}, Epilog -> {lines}]
```

And put it at the end of the `GridBox` function behind your plots

```
answer=GridBox[Join[
   Table[Plot[functions[[i]], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], {{"",
      legend, ""}}]] // DisplayForm
```

Comment: Dear thanks for these valuable hints. One more thing that these legends are shown at the end vertically. How we show these legends horizontally .

Comment: @Amin you would just have to change the `answer` function so that your legend ends up in the {{1,4}} position. So `answer` will have four columns on the first row and three columns in the second. I have not tested, but it should work fine.

Comment: Haff, Dear I am not finding the right place where we can put {{1,4}}, please guide me.

Comment: @Amin Taking the above suggestion, use `GraphicsRow` do create a row filled with graphics:

`GraphicsRow[{GridBox[
    Table[Plot[functions[[i]], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]] // 
   DisplayForm, legend}]`

Also, you can resize the graphics with your mouse after they are displayed.